# android DatagramChannel tunnel must connect to a server in VpnService?

Tags: java, android, network-programming, vpn, android-vpn-service

I'm coding a VPN in android for watch the local network traffic (packet) and let the packets go after inspection. my app is base on `ToyVPN`, so far i can receive the packets but i can't send them Through the tunnel. i see the tunnel connects to ('127.0.0.1',9040). My question is, is needed a server to bind on ('127.0.0.1',9040) to respond to other tunnel side? if not? where does the tunnel connect to? Basically how this tunnel works?

 see a part of the code:

```
  public void run() {
            try {
                //a. Configure the TUN and get the interface.
                mInterface = builder.setSession("MyVPNService")
                        .addAddress("192.168.1.0", 24)
                        .addDnsServer("8.8.8.8")
                        .addRoute("0.0.0.0", 0).establish();
                //b. Packets to be sent are queued in this input stream.
                FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(
                        mInterface.getFileDescriptor());
                //b. Packets received need to be written to this output stream.
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(
                        mInterface.getFileDescriptor());
                //c. The UDP channel can be used to pass/get ip package to/from server
                DatagramChannel tunnel = DatagramChannel.open();

                // Connect to the server, localhost is used for demonstration only.
                tunnel.connect(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 9040));
                //d. Protect this socket, so package send by it will not be feedback to the vpn service.
                protect(tunnel.socket());
                tunnel.configureBlocking(false);
                ByteBuffer packet = ByteBuffer.allocate(MAX_PACKET_SIZE);
                Log.d("hixnal","tunnel open:" + tunnel.isOpen() + " connected:" + tunnel.isConnected());
                //e. Use a loop to pass packets.
                int timer = 0;
                int p=0;
                while (true) {
                    boolean idle = true;
                    int length= in.read(packet.array());
                    if (length > 0) {
                        p++;
                        Log.d("hixnal",p+"");
                        packet.limit(length);
                        //debugPacket(packet);
                        //tunnel.write(packet);
```